# How to sum 2d and 1d arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Supposing I have 2d and 1d numpy array. I want to add the second array to each subarray of the first one and to get a new 2d array as the result.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
>>> b = np.array([2, 3])
>>> c = ... # <-- What should be here?
>>> c
array([[3, 5],
       [5, 7],
       [7, 9],
       [9, 22]])
```

I could use a loop but I think there're standard ways to do it within numpy.

What is the best and quickest way to do it? Performance matters.

Thanks.

Comment: ......... `a+b`?

Comment: Did you really not even try `a+b`?

Comment: Is `a+b` the quickest solution? I actually got an error of using `a+b`... But it works for my question.

Comment: numpy incorporates elements of functional programming, so it's easy to miss `a+b` coming from plain-old-python.

Comment: What do you get with `a.dtype` for your actual case?

Comment: @Divakar I have solved my actual case thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments are missing the explanation of why a+b works. It's called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Basically if you have a NxM matrix and a Nx1 vector, you can directly use the `+` operator to "add the vector to each row of the matrix.

This also works if you have a 1xM vector and want to add it columnwise.

Broadcasting also works with other operators and other Matrix dimensions.

Take a look at the documentation to fully understand [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)